# Como montar um gráfico Stackedcolumn100?

Tags: c#, jquery, highcharts

Estou retornando um consulta do banco para um `DataTable` e serializando a mesma para `Json`.

Uso o seguinte metodo para Serializar meu DataTable para Json.

```
 public static string ConvertDataTabletoString(DataTable dt)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }
```

**E otenho o seguinte Resultado:**

> [{"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq.
>   Convencionais","data":"[96]"},{"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng.
>   Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[95.51]"},{"name":"DIFS - GEMAS -
>   GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[89.7]"},{"name":"DIFS -
>   GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq.
>   Convencionais","data":"[97.05]"},{"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng.
>   Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[86.86]"},{"name":"DIFS - GEMAS -
>   GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[90]"},{"name":"DIFS -
>   GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[47.35]"}]

Meu código está certo, você pode vê-lo aqui no [JSFIELD.](http://jsfiddle.net/mqq9rd1n/)

[Aqui está código completo.](https://jsfiddle.net/xysg4b86/)

Descobrir que a unica coisa errada seria na propriedade `data`, que ao invés de `"data":[86.86]` está `"data":"[86.86]"`. Há alguma forma de controlar isso?

Comment: Faz `var data = JSON.parse(resultadoDoServidor);`. Isso deve chegar para converter os dados.

Comment: @Sergio Chega aparecer o Gráfico mais não plota os dados.

Comment: Podes mostrar como estás a usar os dados no JS?

Comment: @Sergio Posso sim, estou tentando aqui.

Comment: Mas nesse jsFiddle o `series: [{` já está certo... como estás a importar isso do C#?

Comment: @Sergio eu retirei na mão as aspas do valor do data. Do C# vem como no resultado acima.

Comment: Mas estás a imprimir isso direto dentro do JS? Podes pôr essa parte do código aqui na pergunta? a parte em que compilas o JS com os dados lá dentro...

Comment: @Sergio A função do amigo abaixo funciona, falta só converter deserializar o objeto para Array.

Comment: Coloca pf o código que imprime na página o JS.

Comment: @Sergio é o resultado acima. Porem eu usei  var data = JSON.parse(resultadoDoServidor);

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23236/discussion-between-sergio-and-marconi).

Comment: @Sergio viu o resultado que mostrei?

Comment: Estou no trabalho e com pouco tempo. Vi a resposta sim. Tens isso online? Acho que o parse do JSON está a correr mal. Queria ver o que o servidor envia no developer tools. Mas se passares essa resposta do servidor sem usar o `type: 'json'` no AJAX, podias fazer o parse dentro da função success do jQuery... Mas preciso testar. A solução do @Malaba funciona, mas é remendo. O objeto já devia estar limpo, sem precisar de um `.map()`  e muito menos com RegExp para limpar aspas que envolvem uma array...

Comment: @Sergio Entendi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue solução em JS.

```
var dados = [{"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[96]"},
             {"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[95.51]"},
             {"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[89.7]"},
             {"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[97.05]"},
             {"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[86.86]"},
             {"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[90]"},
             {"name":"DIFS - GEMAS - GAECS - Eng. Man. Eq. Convencionais","data":"[47.35]"}];
```

Converta o JSON para uma lista de objetos usando o [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) da seguinte forma:

```
var dados = JSON.parse(dados);
```

Use a função [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) para interar sobre a lista:

```
var seriesDados = $.map(dados, function(data, i){
   return {
     name: data['name'],
       //expressão regular que remove tudo diferente de 0-9 (caracteres numéricos) e ponto(.)
       data: [parseFloat(data['data'].replace(/[^0-9.]/g,""))]
   };
});
```

E nas series coloque a variável teste.